# Problem using SPI2 on a Nucleo-H7 whereas SPI1 works fine

Tags: stm32, gpio, spi, nucleo

My setup is the following: a Nucleo board (Nucleo 144 embedding a STM32H743) is configured as SPI Master. Another identical board is configured as SPI Slave.

For the Master I setup the SPI1 (pins GND, D11, D12 and D13 - PA5,6,7- of the CN7 connector) with following config:

- GPIO: very high speed, alternate function 5
- SPI: prescaler DIV8, interrupts enabled, simplex communication, no Slave Select
- all clocks set to maximum (CPU 400MHz, etc...)

For the Slave I setup the SPI1 too (same pins), **it works fine.**

Then I tried to switch to SPI2 peripheral for the Slave board and could not make it work (no change to master board).
I chose the pins D18 (PB13) for SCK, A7 (PC2) for MISO and A2 (PC3) for MOSI.

I've checked the following points:

- SPI2 periph clock is enabled
- GPIOB and C clocks are enabled and pins PB13, PC2 and PC3 are set up the same way as PA5,6,7 in previous setup.
- for the GND I tried different GND pins on the board, I don't know if it makes a difference.
- the GPIOs used for SPI2 are not used elsewhere in my code. I've got them from the datasheet of STM32H743ZI

What I see:

- my slave is still receiving the SCK signal correctly: I get the correct number of RXP interrupts.
- the data received by the slave is corrupted.
- however the data send by the slave to the master is correct.

I think the MOSI signal is badly configured, either physically or logically. I tried the other GPIO pins whose alternate function can be SPI2_MOSI but same behaviour.

Is there a specificity to SPI2 and/or this GPIO setup ? Does the GND location on the board matter ?

Answer (score 0):

I "fixed" (?) the issue by setting a pull-down to the SPI2 input GPIO on Slave side. I don't really understand why it was working without pull-down on SPI1 neither why this pull down is needed on a Slave ?

Comment: Check what mode your SPI is actually being run in. Clock polarity and phase may explain the issue.